# java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! running Junit in Android project

Tags: android, junit4

In an android project I try to run simple junit tests. They always fail with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:5)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:7)
at com.my.android.JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(JsonParser.java:27)
at com.my.android.test.JsonParser_Test.getJson(JsonParser_Test.java:19)
```

This is the line it fails, any new Class initiation would do that.

```
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ...
 }
```

In several posts I found that the `junit` jar should be included before the `Android SDK`. I did that in `IntelliJ`, but I did not help. I am using `junit 4.9` and `Android SDK 4.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I think robolectric can be useful for you.

> Running tests on an Android emulator or device is slow! Building, deploying, and launching the app often takes a minute or more. That’s no way to do TDD. There must be a better way.
>
> Wouldn’t it be nice to run your Android tests directly from inside
>   your IDE? Perhaps you’ve tried, and been thwarted by the dreaded
>   'java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!'?

http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/

Comment: Yes thanks I already had a look at it. Looks nice. But in this case need simple junit test, without starting the whole android stuff.

Comment: Maybe you can run the tests as a normal Java project, and use the Apache HttpComponents (http://hc.apache.org/) dependency for the DefaultHttpClient class?